# Linear Regression: Minimizing proposed changes to the response variable with a goal of statistical insignificance?

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I am performing a linear regression for a pay equity analysis. That regression will typically look something like this (where *yearsOfExperience* is a stand-in for one or many controls that may be included):

$$
compensation = \beta_0 + \beta_1isFemale + \beta_2yearsOfExperience + \epsilon
$$

So, we'll run the regression and possibly tell the client "it looks like your coefficient for *isFemale* is significant and negative". They'll want to know "what is the cheapest possible remediation dollar amount that I have to distribute to make it such that my gender pay gap is no longer statistically significant"?

In other words, I need to minimize proposed increases in the response variable (for a subset of observations) that changes the model such that the p-value associated with the *isFemale* coefficient increases above a threshold (often 0.1).

I'm currently executing a binary search, which probably gets me "pretty close" to the minimization:

1. I fix "budget distribution %" to be based on the relative size of each underpaid woman's residual. (neither "females with positive residuals" nor "males" would get any proposed compensation increases)
2. come up with a high overall budget "guess" and low overall budget "guess"
3. get the midpoint of those guesses
4. distribute that amount to underpaid women based on the % value explained in (1)
5. re-fit the model to see whether *isFemale* is still significantly associated with lower pay.
6. If my p-value is above 0.1, I adjust my guess downward, and if my p-value is still below 0.1, I adjust my guess upward. Then I start again at (4).

Since this involves iteratively re-fitting the model, it can be computationally expensive. I also can't be sure I'm truly getting the minimum remediation amount as I have to fix the distribution % in step 1.

I have tried minimization (via `scipy.optimize`), but the constraints are non-differentiable. Methods like `basinhopping` don't seem to allow for the constraints that I'd need either. Is there a more elegant statistical method to solve this problem?

Comment: Ignore what I posted. I hadn't considered changes to the overall variability in the pay.

Comment: The optimum is attained by sampling four or fewer employees.  The point is that statistical significance depends on how hard you work to obtain data.  This is scarcely a defensible criterion for adjusting pay scales!  A more meaningful question to ask is *how should the business adjust its pay scales to be equitable* without regard to (essentially irrelevant) questions of statistical significance.

Comment: I certainly agree, and so does my employer. But lawsuit prevention is still a problem deemed profitable to solve.

Comment: It will help if you can write the p-value on $\beta_1$ as a function of the data and the predictions. Once you do that, you can add a $``+c"$ to the female employees and find the smallest value of $c$ such that the p-value is above your threshold for significance.

Comment: With this procedure, aren't you over-committing to one particular functional form for "equal pay"? Say you minimize budget with the constraint that p-value is 0.1. Just including / excluding / transforming one predictor might bring the p-value below 0.1. So how are you going to convince everyone that you have the one true formula for equal pay? And why no interactions between gender and the covariates?